# How to get data from one-to-many relationship table while working with asp.net core and mongodb

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have two tables service and sub service as:

```
 public class Service
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
Public class subservice{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string SubServiceName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Service Service { get; set; }
    public string ServiceId { get; set; }
}
```

I am using generic repository pattern .I am unable to retrieve data from service table through subservice table.How can I retrieve data of service table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have mongodb set up correctly, You have to call `.Include(x => x.Service)` on the DbSet